# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' to type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' ABP Framework with in-memory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, abp

Registering the in-memory database as SQL lite

```
private static void RegisterSqliteInMemoryDb(IIocManager iocManager)
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<LegalRegTechDbContext>();

    var inMemorySqlite = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
    builder.UseSqlite(inMemorySqlite);
    inMemorySqlite.Open();
    
    iocManager.IocContainer.Register(
        Component
            .For<DbContextOptions<LegalRegTechDbContext>>()
            .Instance(builder.Options)
            .LifestyleSingleton()
    );
    IWebHostEnvironment mockEnviroment = new FakeHostingEnvironment();

    new LegalRegTechDbContext(builder.Options, mockEnviroment).Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

In the Db Context I have the below code

```
public LegalRegTechDbContext(DbContextOptions<LegalRegTechDbContext> options, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    : base(options)
{
    var connection = (SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();

    if (env != null)
    {
        var configuration = env.GetAppConfiguration();
        if (configuration.GetValue<bool>("RequiresTokenAccess"))
        {
            connection.AccessToken =
            (new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider())
            .GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Getting an exception as System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' to type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. from this code `var connection = (SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();`

**Packages**

```
<PackageReference Include="Abp.MemoryDb" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="5.0.8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.

[SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection) refers to an MSSQL connection.  MSSQL is a *COMPLETELY DIFFERENT* kind of database from SQLite!  Hence the error.

Your actual database is one or the other.  Install the appropriate Nuget packages and use the correct MS Data object classes as needed.

Comment: But for the testing I need to use SQL in-memory database, however, the real database is MS-SQL. I have above packages install on test project

Comment: the error message is self-explanatory: you're casting to the wrong type. If the runtime object is a SqliteConnection, then you CAN'T just cast it to an MSSQL SqlConnection. Ideally, you can just get rid of the cast.  Worst case, you might have to refactor your code. It's as simple as that!